# I have a problem in integration using Trapezoidal method using python. My function tends to infinity at the upper limit. How to handle this?

Tags: python

My function that needs to be integrated is g(t) = 1/(0.003172*0.001*(3.3-t)). The lower and upper limits of integration are a=0 and b=3.3 and taking number of sub-intervals, n=20. When I run the code, I am getting 'float division by zero' error.

```
def Trapezoidal(f, a, b, n):
    h = (b-a)/float(n)
    s = 0.5*(f(a) + f(b))
    for i in range(1,n,1):
        s = s + f(a + i*h)
    return h*s

def g(t):
    
    return (1/(0.003172*0.001*(3.3-t)))

a = 0;  b = 3.3
n = 20
result = Trapezoidal(g, a, b, n)
print (result)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your execution is on this block

```
def g(t):
    
    return (1/(0.003172*0.001*(3.3-t)))
```

As when you pass 3.3 value while calling f(b) the denominator in the return statement of g(t) function becomes 0. i.e.

```
def g(t):
    
    return (1/(0.003172*0.001*(3.3-3.3))) --->1/0
```

Which gives error

To solve this error for 3.3
Follow.

```
try:
        s = 0.5*(f(a) + f(b))
        for i in range(1,n,1):
            s = s + f(a + i*h)
        return h*s
except:
        return "invalid input"
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But I can't change 3.3 . That needs to be there. What should I do now?

Comment: That means this problem cannot be solve for value 3.3. so one of the possible way to resolve this would be to return invalid input from Trapaezoidal. I have edited code to show how to return invalid input for input 3.3